# Files from windows user in git VCS?

Tags: windows, macos, git

I'm feeling slow here today but I'm attempting to merge some code from a third party developer who is NOT using git.  He is manually sending me files from his windows machine in India where he has edited them with dreamweaver (currently he has the line ending type set to "CR").  When I get the files, on my MacOSX machine, they have windows line endings (^M in vim) so I strip them with this perl command `perl -pe 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\n/g' orders.dev.php > orders.php` which strips the windows line endings and works great in the file editors I have.  The problem is when I try to add that file to git the entire file shows as changed.  If the line termination was windows that would make sense to me but I'm stripping that.  After doing some googling I found this github post https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings which looks like I can use git to force a specific line ending or in Mac's case tell it to use whatever the file has none of which seemed to make any difference for me.  Bottom line I can't figure out how to show the changes the actual developer made.  It always shows the entire file changed.  What am I missing?

P.S. Sorry for the length but wanted to show I'm not just throwing a question out there.  I have looked into it.  Just for some reason have yet to stumble on what I'm missing (other then a second cup of coffee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `git diff -w`, you'll ignore whitespaces diff (spaces/tabs, line ending). This should help you seeing the diff .

For git, to force the line ending to be changed to LF (on commit), the command is `git config --global core.autocrlf true`.

Comment: Simon thank you!  The `git diff -w` is exactly what I'm looking for.  I changed core.autocrlf to true and committed the changes which I can't tell if it adjusted the line endings because I manually did that but I'm getting in the version history a file with 100% changed so in the future it will be impossible to tell what actually changed.  Any ideas on fixing that?  Is the reason it's showing up 100% with the line endings stripped some sort of combination of spaces and or tabs?  Thanks again.

Comment: I'd guess tab/space been switched. You'll always be able to use `git diff -w` to watch history correctly. On Github diff pages, just append `?w=1` to the URL to get diffs without whitespaces.

Comment: Simon - Thanks that will have to do!